# cimento package not found

Tags: packages, missing

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{cimento}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\title{Higgs studies}
\author{Higgs}
\instlist{\XXXX University}
\begin{document}
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx
\end{document}
```

The error I got is:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `cimento.cls' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: cls)

Enter file name:
```

Anyone could you please let me know what I should do to solve this problem?

Comment: Get it here: https://www.sif.it/static/SIF/resources/public/files/cimento.zip

Comment: why cimsmple.tex does not producing pdf file?

Comment: To do test without modification when I click on view pdf it shows me that file does not found?

Comment: Have a look at this one https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: Is there any news here?

Answer (score 3):

Class `cimento.cls` is very simple so you can create a new directory and copy all files from `cimento.zip` into it.

Now copy your given MWE as file `426795.tex` into the same directory and compile. You get no errors and the following directory:

[image: directory]

and the following pdf:

[image]

Compiling file `cimsmple.tex` results in 7 errors and 5 warnings, so that I suggest you ask for an updated version of this class or use simple another one, for example `report` or `book`.

The error with the `table` environment can be fixed by adding

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{table}[1][\fps@table]
 {%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\@float{table}[#1]}\x
  \small\@intable@true
  \def\tnotes{\smallskip\par\smaller}%
  \def\tnote##1{\par$({##1})$}%
 }
 {\@intable@false\end@float}
\makeatother
```

in the document preamble (before `\begin{document}`).

Comment: I added the fix for the errors. A bug report has already been filed with the class maintainer.